# I want to colour band a pyplot background

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want to colourband the background of a pyplot in a similar way to the attached image.  I have no problem graphing the stochastic line, I just want it to overlay on some the bands to visually establish at which points things change. The bands need to be a fixed width in the x-axis (0-3, 3-7,7-..etc.) The y value is not constant from plot to plot, so the bands need to go to 0-yMin (I'm dealing with depth) each plot.
I have experimented with trying arrays/bar graphs and importing and stretching images but neither seem to work. [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdqNv.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Axes.axhspan(self, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, facecolor="color")` method ([see reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhspan.html)) to set parts of the graph background different colours.

Note that the `ymin` and `ymax` parameters refer to the actual y values on the graph while the `xmin` and `xmax` parameters should be scaled to values between 0 and 1 (0 referring to the start of the x-axis and 1 referring to the end).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# generate random data
elevation = [random.randrange(-y -1, 0) for y in range(10)]
distance = range(10)

# get reference to axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot data with a yellow line
ax.plot(distance, elevation, 'y', linewidth=3)

# format axes
ax.grid()
ax.margins(0)
ax.set_ylabel('elevation (m)')
ax.set_xlabel('position')
ax.set_ylim([min(elevation) - 1, max(elevation) + 1])

# get range of axes
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmax = max(distance)

# set background colours
ax.axhspan(ymin, ymax, 0 / xmax, 3 / xmax, facecolor='green')
ax.axhspan(ymin, ymax, 3 / xmax, 8 / xmax, facecolor='brown')
ax.axhspan(ymin, ymax, 8 / xmax, 9 / xmax, facecolor='blue')

# display graph
plt.show()
```

[image: graph with background color]